# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf ошибка 404

Tags: spring-boot, http-status-code-404, thymeleaf

Использую SpringBoot + thymeleaf, проект стартует без ошибок, но при заходе на localhost:8080 в браузере отображает ошибку Whitelabel Error Page.

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

WebController.java

```
public class WebController {

@Value("${welcome.message:test}")
private String message = "Hello world";

@RequestMapping("/")
public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
    model.put("message",this.message);
    return "welcome";
}
```

}

src/main/resources/templates/welcome.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Spring Boot Thymeleaf Hello World Example</title>
 </head>
<body>
 <div>
    <h1>Spring Boot Web Thymeleaf Example</h1>
    <h2>
        <span th:text="'Message: ' + ${message}"></span>
    </h2>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

application.properties

```
welcome.message: Hello Mkyong
```

Подскажите, что я не правильно делаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что не указал аннотацию @Controller + изменил @RequestMapping("/") на @GetMapping

Comment: можно ещё `@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = GET)`